# how to get Image from amchart div programmatically(asp.net c#) and save in a root folder?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, amcharts

Function to fill `amcharts(pie chart)`.
Please help me out to get `Image(PNG,JPG)` of this Chart output so that I can use that image in generating pdf using `ITextSharp`.

```
 function fillPieChart1() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "frmDashBoardReport.aspx/ProgramProject",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) 
            {
                var data_array = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                //data_array[0].Title
                var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", 
                    {
                    "type": "pie",
                    "theme": "light",

                    "fontSize": 14,
                     "dataProvider": data_array,
                    "titles": [
                                {
                                    "size": 14,
                                    "text": "Number Of Projects Applied"
                                }
                              ],

                     "valueField": "vBit",
                    "titleField": "ProjectName",
                    "descriptionField":"ProgramName",

                    "export": 
                        {
                          "enabled": true
                        }
                        });
                        },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Got an Error');
            }
        });

    }
```

Below is an example output of `Amchart` and I want this chart as an image in PDF using `ITextSharp`.

[image: That the output of Amchart and i want this chart as image in pdf using itextsharp]

Comment: But amcharts can export the graph to png, pdf, etc

Comment: how to export , can u help me please , thanks in advance.

Comment: As you see the graph as export features: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/

Comment: But i need that image to save in root folder of Server so that i can insert in Pdf using ItextSharp. ????